# How to manually trigger a background sync (for testing)?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, background-sync

In Chrome, is there any way to manually trigger a [background sync](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync) for testing/development purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use a force sync in developer tools in Chrome on your service worker.

Go Dev Tools --> Application --> Service Worker and you will see Sync button and next to it a space to write commands.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in Chrome right now (April 2016). Follow [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604697) for updates.